# Opening tabs in Google Chrome crashes my system

Tags: google-chrome, crash

When I open tabs to sites such as BBC iPlayer I have about a 4/5 chance that it will crash my entire system. The system can remain unresponsive for up to 30 mins or as little as 2. This has only happened recently and is becoming very annoying as the rest of my system can be running perfectly fine then I open a tab and it hangs.

It isn't always flash media webpages so I have ruled that out and I have check my addons opened them in incognito mode, done all the usual error checking.

All drivers are up to date. 
The system have a 8core pile-driver 8GB of ram on a cross-hair motherboard so it should be able to handle a little browser issue.

Comment: How many processes are running on your system?  OS etc

Comment: Did you try updating the drivers? Video, graphic, audio, chipset? Does it only happen in Chrome? Does FireFox behave?

Comment: it will crash with only chrome running as a main process, and all the other processes combined only comes to about 25K so nothing strenuous. All drivers are up to date.

Comment: Yes all other browsers are fine it's just Chrome

Comment: Have you updated Chrome?

Comment: it automatically updates as standard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out there was a conflict between flash and my AMD processor, I had to change some settings for my processor and it appears to be working fine now.